# How to write data to parquet when using UDF for Array

Tags: apache-spark

```
val sc = sparkSession.sparkContext
val df = sparkSession.read.json("D:\\tempData\\dimuser.json")
import sparkSession.implicits._
val my_size = udf { subjects: Seq[Row] => subjects.size }
df.select($"username",my_size($"devices").alias("devcount")).write.parquet("D:\\tempData\\userdata.parquet")
```

The program is to calculate the number of device of each user. And I am trying to write a UDF but not the size funcation provided by official. I can run show() function to preview the result. But when i try to write the data into file, i got the following error, seems like type mismatch(as you can see below what the error show is just the schema of the json file).

`Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function(anonfun$1: (array<struct<_id:struct<$oid:string>,ct:struct<$date:string>,devicetoken:string,isInstalledApp:bigint,isinstalledapp:bigint,ismaster:bigint,lastloginduration:bigint,lastloginlocation:string,lastloginstatus:bigint,lastlogintime:struct<$date:string>,mac:string,name:string,os:string,status:string,type:string,uuid:string>>) => int)`

Comment: Are you sure `devices` is of type `array`? You could also try to use the build-in function `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.size` to get the size of an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for another 'Caused by' in error trace, but probably a null pointer exception

> Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function ...
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

`val my_size = udf{subjects:Seq[Row] => if(subjects == null) 0 else subjects.size}`

or wrapped in Option

`val my_size = udf{subjects:Seq[Row] => if(subjects == null) None else Some(subjects.size)}`